# Removing all directories except the 10 newest

Tags: bash, build

How in bash would I remove all directories except the newest five created directories (by date created time)?

This is being used by a build script, and we want to clear up old builds. Thanks.

Edit: Date modified time is also fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not trivial to get a files creation time. See here for reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created

But if your happy to the last modification time instead (which should be fine here?) then something like this one-liner should do.

`ls -dt */ | tail -n +6 | xargs rmdir`

- `ls -d */` list directories `-t` lists them in order
- `tail -n +6` prints all but the last five lines
- `xargs rmdir` calls `rm -r` on each of those dirs (or you can use `rm -r` if they're non-empty)

Comment: it may be +6 to skip 5 first and start at line 6

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with ls but parsing ls output is not safe.

As there is no shell builtin to retrieve file time a solution using perl.

```
perl -e '
    @A = sort {(stat($a))[9]<=>(stat($b))[9]} <*/>;
    rmdir for splice (@A,0,-10)
'
```

Test

```
mkdir tmp && cd tmp
for d in {A..Z}; do mkdir "$d"; done
ls

perl -e '
    @A = sort {(stat($a))[9]<=>(stat($b))[9]} <*/>;
    rmdir for splice (@A,0,-10)
'

ls
```

EDIT: `splice(@A,0,-10)` could be changed to `@A[0..$#A-10]`, maybe easier to read. To get all elements except the last 10.